# how to plot a histogram using pyplot package in python on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to plot a histogram graph on jupyter Notebook  where the data are extract from a dataframe  for visualize the positive and negative sentiment of each record from the dataset used.

The problem is that once i try to plot the result display the below error and display an empty visualization.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-8903e5cb1735> in <module>
      5 plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
      6 plt.xlim(0,45)
----> 7 plt.xlabel("word count")
      8 plt.ylabel("frequency")
      9 g = plt.hist([x,y],color=["r","b"],alpha=0.5,label=["positive","negative"])

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

[image]

## code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plot word count distribution for both positive and negative sentiment
x= df_tweet_preds["word count"][df_tweet_preds.predictions ==1]
y= df_tweet_preds["word count"][df_tweet_preds.predictions ==0]
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.xlim(0,45)
plt.xlabel("word count")
plt.ylabel("frequency")
g = plt.hist([x,y],color=["r","b"],alpha=0.5,label=["positive","negative"])
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
```

Comment: Can you include more of the code? I can't reproduce the error

Comment: the problem is solved now it was the problem in the jupyter kernel like it was freeze  and after several restart for the kernel the visualization  is displayed.
thanks for your comment